# Is it possible to change the track being played no matter the audio player?

Tags: android, media-player

I don't think this is possible but I don't know everything so I better just ask...

Is it possible for me to develop an Android app where I can change to a specific track being played no matter the audio player being used? I mean, all of them use the built-in "media server" to play audio files, right? Maybe that doesn't mean anything...

I wanted to develop this app where the track would automatically change to another according to some specific dynamic information but I didn't want to develop my own audio player for that, I wanted to use whatever the user's preference is on that field.

Do I have any other choice other than developing an audio player?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot, unless, the other apps support this feature.

If the other apps support a specific broadcast or intent, then you could. But the only way to do this, considering the well-known audio players people use, I think you have to create your own player.

Comment: I thought as much... That's too bad. The idea for this app was nice, but having to build an audio player too, just takes a lot more work than it was already going to be. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is stop you from using MediaPlayer?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

If you mean if they have another app that plays music and you want to change the song that the other app is playing that probably will not work.

It may be possible to interface with AudioManager but that is doubtfull.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html

You would be better off finding an open source meida player app and add your functionality into it.